# 16.04 - Login loop after updating OS

Tags: 16.04, login

I was already on 16.04, made an update and now I have login issues, it is looping. Is there any file I can look for crash log or anything that I could try?

Already tried everything on post [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
and still not working. My screen resolution is also wrong now so maybe it has relation with video card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nvidia card, everytime you have an upgrade for some reason I still don't know why, it is deleting the driver. So how I fixed it: downloading and installing the driver once more.

For nvidia users:

`ctrl+alt+f1` and do the login, then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get nvidia-370 (370 in my case, may change)
```

Comment: I tried 364 and 370 and neither of these worked.